# Windows unexpected shutdown after startup the startup applications not running

Tags: windows-server-2019

We are running a cloud VPS with Windows Server 2019. When the server has an unexpected shutdown due to for example a power shortage or hardware failure the server will be auto started afterward. Because it went down unexpected a popup is waiting telling us that the server went down unexpectedly. The popup is shown upon connecting to the VPS through an RDP session.

The problem trough is that we have some applications that are in the auto start folder that after the unexpected shutdown + restart will not run. In order to fully start all required applications we need to manually connect to the RDP, close the unexpected popup and start the applications.

My question is: is windows capable to startup the startup items even when a server has had an unexpected shutdown, without requiring us to manually close the popup and start the apps.

We do receive an e-mail that the server went down unexpectedly but we only work on workhours so if for example the server crashes at 22:00 we come back the following day at 8:30 and take action. So the apps have a downtime of ~10,5 hours.

Sidenote: not all the startup apps have a Windows Service capability and thereby are required to be started trough the startup applications folder.

I did a search on my question both trough google and Stack Exchange but couldn't find an answer.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: whyy not usum nssm for this job?

Comment: Why don't you set up monitoring and alerts so that you get an alert at the time of the unexpected shut down and can fix it at that time? Why don't you ask your VPS provider why there are power outages or hardware failures that cause your server to unexpectedly shut down?

Comment: @djdomi With nssm your are referring to software listed on [link]|(https://nssm.cc/) correct? I do not fully understand how that would help our case.. would this piece of software run even after an unexpected shutdown, withouth us requiring to connect to the RDP to close the unexpected shutdown messagebox? Or would this just be an alternative te run executables that dont have a service companion?

Comment: @joeqwerty The server is not down allot, it was just an incident. Nervertheless we would like to take appropriate actions before other parties notice that services are down. Monitoring alerts also require us to take action after the fact, I would rather have the server skip the popup en continue the startup process. As i've mentioned, the VPS provider already sends us an e-mail so we are notified.

Comment: Hi Jordi, yes I speak about the non sucking service manager which allows you to run any kind of program as a service. this will run that with the settings you set

Comment: @djdomi Thank you for your reply. But will this program, and the configured applications within that start even when the server reboot is "halted" due to the popup prior to connecting with an RDP session to the VPS?

Comment: I don't understand the question, services itself doesn't care about the user, they can bet set to: disabled, manual automatic and delayed, be more specific or attach an Screenshot you can even run a shellscriot as service if you like to

Comment: @djdomi As far as I understand due to an unexpected server shutdown and restart the Windows OS haltst the startup proces with a popup informing the user of the unexpected shutdown. I'm not certain if the halt mechanism does or does not start the Windows services before the user closes that popup. It for certain doesn't start the startup programs. Thats the whole point, I want to fully start the server, even on after an unexpected shutdown without us needing to connect to the VPS trough RDP.

Comment: no, that's usually only a informal pop-up the server does not care about never hearing about that it's blocking